# Why is the divergence of Cauchy stress equal to zero in the reference domain?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

**Below are three configurations of a body: The current one, the reference, and the natural one. The natural reference is when the configuration is pre-stressed. Why is the divergence of Cauchy stress equal to zero in the reference domain? And what's the physical meaning of that? Thank you.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/652862/195949

Comment: Thanks! So, reference configuration is in equilibrium, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a consequence of the equilibrium of forces.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the paper assumes that the only forces which are taking place are internal stresses and that the reference domain is in equilibrium.
On the mathematical side, I am assuming that all the system is at rest (in equilibrium) in an inertial reference frame and that the Cauchy stress tensor is $C^1$. I want to prove that
$$\sigma_{ij},_j(p)=0$$
for every point $p$ in the reference domain. The comma henceforth denotes the derivative with respect to the Cartesian orthonormal coordinate  $x_j$.

Consider a point $p$ in (the interior of) the reference domain and a ball $B_r(p)$ centered on $p$ with radius $r>0$ completely included in the reference domain. The equilibrium requirement of every portion of the reference domain implies (where I use the convention of summation over repeated indices)
$$\int_{+\partial B_r(p)} \sigma_{ij} n_j dS=0\:,$$
because the component $i=1,2,3$ of total force exerted on the boundary of the  ball by the external part of the continuum must be zero.
The divergence theorem yields
$$\int_{B_r(p)} \sigma_{ij},_j dv =0\:.$$
Now assume that $\sigma_{ij},_j(p) = v >0$. The case $<0$ is completely analogous. Since $\sigma_{ij},_j(q)$ is continuous when $q \in B_r(p)$, for every fixed $\epsilon>0$, we can find a second ball $B_\delta(p)$ with $\delta>0$ such that $|\sigma_{ij},_j(q) - v| < \epsilon$ and thus $\sigma_{ij},_j(q) > v-\epsilon$ in particular if $q \in B_\delta(p)$.
Hence, if choosing $\epsilon$ such that $v-\epsilon>0$ (that is always possible since $v>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ can be chosen arbitrarily small) we would have
$$\int_{B_\delta(p)} \sigma_{ij},_j dv \geq  (v-\epsilon) \int_{B_\delta(p)} 1 dv >0\:.$$
This is impossible because
$$\int_{B_e(p)} \sigma_{ij},_j dv=0$$
for every choice of $p$ and  $r>0$. The other case $\sigma_{ij},_j(p) <0$ produces a similar contradiction, We conclude that
$$\sigma_{ij},_j(p)=0$$
for every point internal to the reference domain. The result is valid also for the points on the boundary of the reference domain because $\sigma_{ij},_j(p)=0$ is assumed to be continuous in the closed set.